# Reducing PDE's to canonical form - does order of differentiation matter?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Silly question, but when you're reducing PDE's to canonical form, does order of differentiation matter? I think I remember (vaguely) from calculus that d^2/dxdy = d^2/dydx - does this also apply to things in canonical form?

I.e, does Fi(sub (epsilon, eta)) = Fi (sub (eta, epsilon)) ?

Answer (score 0):

When doing Partial Differentiating, it does not matter with respect to which variable you differentiate first ie :
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x_1\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}$$

This result extends to more than just second derivative.

You can find more information on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).